# increase server timeout in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I want to increase the server time out in eclipse but not sure how server is configured in my eclipse, I was not able to find timeout settings anywhere. Check the screenshot of my project.

I have tried Windows > Show Views > Server but nothing happens... no windows is shown
I have tried Windows > Perefences > Server see the screenshot here I cannot find timeout settings

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Tomcat Server's timeout in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845219/change-tomcat-servers-timeout-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

[image]goto server view, double click on one of the server, expand time out option and set value to it

Comment: server view window is not opening.

Comment: it must be opened some where may be

Comment: how to find where it is opened

Comment: And here I was doing right click->properties on the server in the server view. Never thought to double-click it. This is why I hate Eclipse :(

Answer (score 11):

To see your `server` in `server view` of `eclipse`(**if server view is not coming, simply right click on the perspective e.g. Java or J2EE and select reset**. Hope that helps),

```
    right click (in server server view pane) -> new -> server
```

You will see below screen:

[image]

Now select `Apache` `Tomcat` with right version, then select next, you will see screen below:

[image]

Browse the `Tomcat` server installation directory and finish. Now you will be able to see the `Tomcat` server in server view of the eclipse.

As a last step of your problem, double click on the `Tomcat` server listed in the server view of eclipse and change the timeout as in screen below:
[image]

Hope this helps!.

Answer (score 5):

This is what you need to do:

```
Open the Servers view -> double click tomcat -> click on Timeouts section
```

Make changes according to your requirement.

refer: [Change Tomcat Server's timeout in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845219/change-tomcat-servers-timeout-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

`Open the Servers view -> double click tomcat -> drop down the Timeouts section`

There you can increase the startup time for each particular server.

Comment: duplicated answer

Answer (score 0):

Open the Servers view -> double click tomcat -> Server and Click Open ..

you can increase the startup time in Timeouts tag

Specify the time limit to complete server operations.
        starts (in sec) increase 600

Comment: duplicated answer