# Tomcat Server Timeout in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, timeout, tomcat7

I'm having problems with my Tomcat Server in eclipse. I get the following timeout error:

```
Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 45 seconds. 
If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.
```

And this is what I get in the console:

```
Nov 03, 2013 11:59:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program   Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;.
Nov 03, 2013 11:59:58 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property    'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Gift Registry Application' did not find a matching property.
Nov 03, 2013 11:59:59 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 03, 2013 11:59:59 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 03, 2013 11:59:59 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 3088 ms
Nov 03, 2013 11:59:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal 
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 03, 2013 11:59:59 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Nov 03, 2013 12:00:03 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 03, 2013 12:00:03 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 03, 2013 12:00:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3796 ms
```

Could someone please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try increasing the timeout in the server editor?

Comment: I got the same problem. I also noticed 2 additional things: 1) when I click the "Show background operations in progress view"-button while tomcat is starting up, it seems to be stuck at "Preparing launch delegate...". 2) I can access the web application via localhost:8080 in my browser until the timeout occures.

Answer (score 13):

In Eclipse goto

Servers view => double click tomcat => drop down the Timeouts section.

Update time as per your requirement.

Also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12825288/increase-server-timeout-in-eclipse) URL for in detail steps.

Comment: In Eclipse Luna, it is not working. Is there any other solution. Whether i need to switch to any other version of eclipse like **Helios /Kepler**.

Comment: Try Eclipse Mars / Neon.

Answer (score 5):

*Go to **Windows option -> select Preference**.*

Than **Select General ->  Network Connection**.

Than select the Active Provider as **Manual**.

Then restart the tomcat. It will works.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

For me changing Start Time from 45 sec to 10 min and wait for 5 minutes after starting the server solved the problem.