# Tomcat v7.0 server unable to start

Tags: java, tomcat

Previously tomcat server was running fine then without any reason it got stuck and showing an error message.
"Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 45 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor."
 It is having a huge error log, however I am showing some of them

```
    org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: assertion failed: 
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:96)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.EditorStatusLine$StatusLineClearer.selectionChanged(EditorStatusLine.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:164)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:162)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer.fireSelectionChanged(TextViewer.java:2738)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer.selectionChanged(TextViewer.java:2717)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.TextViewer$4.widgetSelected(TextViewer.java:1836)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:774)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.sendSelectionEvent(StyledText.java:8048)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.clearSelection(StyledText.java:1701)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.setSelection(StyledText.java:9507)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.updateSelection(StyledText.java:10215)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.handleTextChanged(StyledText.java:6204)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText$6.textChanged(StyledText.java:5609)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.DefaultDocumentAdapter.fireTextChanged(DefaultDocumentAdapter.java:347)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.DefaultDocumentAdapter.documentChanged(DefaultDocumentAdapter.java:291)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.doFireDocumentChanged2(AbstractDocument.java:760)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.doFireDocumentChanged(AbstractDocument.java:736)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.doFireDocumentChanged(AbstractDocument.java:721)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.fireDocumentChanged(AbstractDocument.java:796)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.projection.ProjectionDocument.fireDocumentChanged(ProjectionDocument.java:777)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:1191)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.replace(AbstractDocument.java:1210)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.projection.ProjectionDocument.replace(ProjectionDocument.java:629)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.DefaultDocumentAdapter.replaceTextRange(DefaultDocumentAdapter.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.modifyContent(StyledText.java:7178)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.sendKeyEvent(StyledText.java:8007)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.doContent(StyledText.java:2467)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.handleKey(StyledText.java:5907)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText.handleKeyDown(StyledText.java:5937)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText$7.handleEvent(StyledText.java:5629)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1104)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1100)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmChar(Widget.java:1521)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_CHAR(Control.java:4640)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.WM_CHAR(Canvas.java:345)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4528)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4976)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2546)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3756)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1029)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:923)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
```

I tried reinstalling apache tomcat then also same thing persists.

Comment: Have you actually tried increasing startup timeout? Also check that you don't have breakpoint set up during server startup... If you have a bit more complex application, it can take up to 90 seconds to start. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12825288/increase-server-timeout-in-eclipse

Comment: Sorry for replying so late, yes I tried increasing the timeout to 90 secs and still no help. Its not the problem with the project but it is not even starting in itself.

Comment: This exception has nothing to do with Tomcat, it is an Eclipse error.

Comment: How can I solve it. I was using eclipse juno now I am getting the same problem with eclipse indigo as well.

Comment: Did you upgrade Eclipse? Create a new empty workspace if so. Eclipse is not good at running using old workspace metadata.

Comment: I guess there was some problem with the project. I copied my entire things to a different project and its working fine. However thanks for your concern.

Comment: Restart You Computer. Then go to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12825288/increase-server-timeout-in-eclipse